# Material Design Side Nav, dynamically add handles issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am working on a project and I need to generate side navs dynamically.

My first reaction is to create md-component-id attributes that are named in the controllers,

```
md-component-id="{{templateName}}"
```

But, it seems that the side nav service tries to register the handle {{templateName}} instead of whatever variable I assigned to it.

Any other thoughts on how I could dynamically create a sidenav bar depending on what a user clicks? For instance, there is a list of users and depending on which user is clicked, it will populate the sidebar with their information.